# C program for palindrome

Tags: c, string

I'm still a beginner coder, and I am having trouble writing a program to check whether a string is a palindrome or not using only `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` libraries.

The string can take at most 30 characters. We must assume that the string can take digits, punctuation characters, and letters. Also, assume there are no spaces in the string. Must differentiate between uppercase and lowercase characters. So "madam" would be a palindrome, but "MaDam" would not be a palindrome. The string ends with a null terminator.
Hi, so when I compile with gcc -Wall. I get these errors. Can someone please explain how I can fix these errors? Thank you for your time.

```
s_palindrome.c:24:15: warning: variable 'length' is used uninitialized whenever
  'for' loop exits because its condition is false
  [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
for (a=0; **a<30**; a++){

is_palindrome.c:36:18: note: uninitialized use occurs here
for (a=0; **a<(length/2)**; a++){

is_palindrome.c:24:15: note: remove the condition if it is always true
for (a=0; **a<30**; a++){

is_palindrome.c:12:18: note: initialize the variable 'length' to silence this
  warning
**int a, length;**= 0
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
char string [30];
int a, l;
int p=1;

printf("Enter a string to test: \n");
scanf("%s", string);

for (a=0; a<30; a++){
    if (string[a]=='\0'){
        l=a;
        break;
    }
}

for (a=0; a<l/2; a++){
    if (string[a]!=string[l-1-a]){
        p=0;
    }
}

if (p){
    printf("%s is a palindrome\n", string);
}
else {
    printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", string);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have shown some code but have not made any mention of it. Does it work? If not, what is its behaviour? That is, why are you asking a very general question rather than relating it to the code you have written?

Comment: There are several errors, both syntactical and logical, in the code you have posted.

Comment: I am reluctantly voting to reopen, as the close reason no longer applies.  Note that the answer to your question is in the warning itself: `note: initialize the variable 'length' to silence this warning`

Comment: so are you saying i should say int l=0?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
char str[30];
int i, len=0;
int flag=1;
printf("Enter a string: \n");
scanf("%s", &str);

for (i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++){
len++;
}
len--;

for(i=0;i<=len/2;i++)
    if(str[i]!=str[len-i])
    {
        flag=0;
        break;
    }

if(flag==1)
    printf("%s is a palindrome. \n", str);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi can you explain what flag means please?

Comment: You're not supposed to just give code away. You need to provide an explanation of the problems which the OP has in their code, and then provide annotated code examples. Your answer has neither of these things

Comment: @user44775 `flag` here is just used as an indicator, that  records whether the loop did not complete its iterations and had to `break` in between or not, which means that its initial value `1` would indicate that the input was a palindrome (loop ran completely) and on the contrary a value of `0` would indicate that the input was not a palindrome (loop broke), which is the check that @Abhay has missed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the corrected version of your code, which I have tested to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    char str[30], temp[30];
    int first, last, e;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    for (first=0; str[first]!='\0'; first++)
    {
     e = first;
    }
    // loop finds the length of the string, e=first is the index of the last character of the string

    // code to store reverse of str in temp
    for (first = 0, last = e; str[first] != '\0'; first++, last--)
    {
     temp[first] = str[last];
    }
    temp[first] = '\0';

    // code to compare str and reverse of str i.e. temp
    for (first=0; str[first]!='\0'; first++)
    {
        // if any character in str and reverse str i.e. temp is unequal, break the loop
        if(str[first]!=temp[first])
        {
         printf("%s is not a palindrome!\n",str);
         break;
        }
    }

   // if loop did not break str and reverse str i.e. temp are equal
   if(str[first]=='\0')
   {
    printf("%s is a palindrome.\n",str);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

There were several problems such as:

- `char string[30];` declared but `str` used instead.
- `e=first` will not be equal to the length of the string, rather it will be one less than it, which makes it the index of the last character of the string.
- This `e` was used wrongly in `for (first=0, first=e; str[first]!='\0',first>=0, first++, last--)`, where `first` is initialized twice, making it lose its initial value. Instead, `last` should have been initialized to e. Also, `for` loop can have multiple initializations as well as increments/decrements (seperated by commas), but not multiple conditions. And the separator between initializations,condition and increments/decrements should be a  semicolon `;`, which was missing in your case.
- There was no need for the `continue;` statements at the end of the loop, because `continue` unlike `break`, is used to stop the current iteration from further execution and move to the next iteration. Since, here you have no more code to execute in the current iteration, the `continue` is superfluous and is not needed.
- The `printf` function was incorrectly used. In this function, you have to provide a **format specifier** as the first input, which is a format of how the output would be rendered. All newline characters '\n', spaces and placeholders for any variables to include in the final output should be specified here in. The rest of the arguments to `printf`, would contain all the variables, for which, placeholders have been defined in the format specifier string passed in as first argument.
- A brace `}` was missing for the last `if`.
- I have corrected the same basic algorithm that you have posted, but, it is not very efficient. A more efficient algorithm, would avoid creating another reverse array. Instead, it would start comparing characters form first and last index in the same string, incrementing first and decrementing last at each step, until the middle character is reached.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems, most of which prevent your program from compiling.

- You define `string` but use `str` everyplace else.  So change the definition to `str`.
- `printf("%s is not a palindrome!"\n);` : The newline is outside the string, and you didn't pass `str` as a parameter to print it.
- `printf("%s is a palindrome. \n");` : Again, `str` is not passed in to print
- `for (first=0, first=e; str[first]!='\0',first>=0, first++, last--){`

  - There are two parts instead of the required 3, i.e. a `;` is missing.  It should go before `first++`.
  - You can't comma separate parts of the conditional.  You have to use some logical connector like `||` or `&&`.  In this case, however, only the first part is needed, so you can remove the second part.
  - You don't initialize `last`.  `first=e` should be `last=e`;
  - Result of fixing the above: `for (first=0, last=e; str[first]!='\0'; first++, last--){`
- Missing `}` just before the `return` at the end.
- Not an error, but `if(str[first]==temp[first]) continue;` can be removed, since you're at the bottom of the loop anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
int valid=1;//is palindrome
for(i=0, j=e; i<j; ++i, --j) {
    if(str[i] != str[j]){
        valid=0;
        break;
    }
}
```

does this help? it looks like you were overthinking this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>`
#include<string.h> 
int main(void)
{
char name[10];
int x,i,r,count = 0;

printf("Enter the Name : ");
scanf("%s",&name);
x = strlen(name);
r = x - 1;

for(i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
{
  if(name[i] == name[r])
  {
   count = count + 1;
  }
  else
  {
   break;
  }
r = r - 1;
}
if(count == x)
 printf("%s is a Palindrome\n",name);
else
 printf("%s is not a Palindrome\n",name);
}
```